# Adding localhost subdomains in apache virtual hosts

Tags: apache, wamp

I am trying to redirect all subdomains of hothouse to go to hothouse\testsite, but I cannot get it to work.

I dont understand the difference between DocumentRoot and VirtualDocumentRoot, not sure if that makes any difference.

Any ideas why it is not working 'testsite.hothouse' redirects fine. 'test.hothouse' or any subdomain.hothouse does not (redirects to 'www.subdomain.hothouse').

I have spent all day trying to work this out I have cleared all my browser caches. BTW I am using WAMP

```
DocumentRoot "D:\wamp\www" 
<Directory "D:\wamp\www"> 
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI 
    AllowOverride All 
    Order allow,deny 
    Allow from all 
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *:80>  
DocumentRoot "D:\wamp\www"
ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>  
VirtualDocumentRoot "D:\wamp\www\hothouse\testsite"
ServerName testsite.hothouse
ServerAlias test.hothouse
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  VirtualDocumentRoot "D:\wamp\www\hothouse\testsite"
  ServerName subdomain.hothouse
  ServerAlias *.hothouse
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: What version of Apache are you running?

Comment: OK I feel stupid, I needed to make the changes to my windows hosts file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was not the apache settings but I hadn't updated my windows host file to redirect to the localhost.